# How are the question integer IDs generated?

Tags: discussion, implementation

I've tried [asking this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303175), but to no avail, and since I don't have the ability to move questions to other parts of Stack Exchange, I'm posting the question here.

Essentially, my question is regarding Stack Exchange's implementation of the numeric ID that gets generated every time a question is created. I'm looking to do something very similar, but in my case it is generating a customer number every time a customer signs up for my site. Since this number is what they will use to log in, I'd like it to be fairly short (in length) so it's not too overwhelming for them to remember. The catch though is that I'm looking for a way to do it in a distributed environment, which means using the `auto increment` won't work here.

I have to assume that a huge site like Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange is distributed, so I would very much like to know how it's able to create these unique integers without any collisions.

Comment: They use auto increment...